# Not able to do Navigation Drawer Below toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout

How to fit the Navigation Drawer under toolbar it's overlaps the main layout.
**activity_set_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    >

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_set_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:itemTextColor ="#FFFFFF"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_set_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_set_main" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**app_bar_set_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.pash.icas_nvod.setMain">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

       >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/bydesign_logo"
            android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_set_main" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**content_set_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_set_main_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#EE7F22"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.pash.icas_nvod.setMain"
    >
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/login_progress"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Above are my xml files am not able make drawer fit under the toolbar.
The drawer layout is overlapping to main layout. How to i resolve it..?
I have searched alot but none of the answer relates to my problem.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_set_main"` in your `DrawerLayout`.

-----OR-----

You can try to move your toolbar out of your drawerlayout. So in my project, i used `LinearLayout` as root layout. I tried to replace with your components, hope it helps.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<include
layout="@layout/app_bar_set_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

/>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start"
>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_set_main" //Add this line also.
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:itemTextColor ="#FFFFFF"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_set_main"
app:menu="@menu/activity_set_main" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit:** Also you must add `android:layout_below` to fit your drawer under toolbar.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response your answer is near about my problem it is helpful for me.

Comment: I'm glad to help you :)